# Running all script in a directory python

Tags: python, batch-file, directory, operating-system

If I have 5 python scripts and they are all in one directory how would I go about running all of them? I dont want to have to go and manually open them and then run them I would like to have python do this.

So i  have a folder named Scripts and inside it has five scripts that all have different names with the .ipynb extension.

so the breakdown of the Tree looks like this,

```
-Scripts
   -A.ipynb
   -B.ipynb
   -C.ipynb
   -D.ipynb
   -E.ipynb
```

How could I run each of the files in this directory without manually opening them and running them each individually?

Comment: First of all, files listed here is not python files. Those are ipython notebooks.

Comment: So can we not run them through the jupyter notebook?

Comment: You can run them through jupyter notebook but it will only open and you have to manually run each block. Instead i would suggest you to create python (.py) files and then you can run all at one go.

Comment: Okay sounds good I will do that then, thanks for the feedback

Comment: A batch file: `for %%F in ("Scripts\*.ipynb") do start "%%~F"`? (or `*.py` files instead?)

Answer (score 0):

The extension 'ipynb' isn't a python script, but, you can create a batch file which runs all of your .py files.

Example:

---

```
@ECHO OFF 
Runs my Python Scripts

C:\path-to-python\Python.exe C:\path-to-scripts\A.py
ECHO Ran script A

(Repeat as needed)

PAUSE
```

---

Comment: I made some changes to this but for the most part it works, except it throws a import error saying it cant find a module. How do I specify I want it to do the batch file through 32 bit because I am fairly certain that it is trying to use 64 that is why I am getting the error